# No puedo hacer Login con un modelo personalizado en Django Admin

Tags: django

Cree una aplicación llamada 'account' donde tengo un modelo con la siguiente información:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
# Create your models here.


class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
   def create_user(self, email,username,password=None):
       if not email:
           raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
       if not username:
           raise ValueError("Users must have an username")
       user = self.model(
           email=self.normalize_email(email),
           username=username,
       )
       user.set_password(password)
       user.save(using=self._db)
       return user
   def create_superuser(self,email,username,password):
   
       user= self.create_user(
           email=self.normalize_email(email),
           username=username,
           password=password,
           
       )
       user.is_admin = True
       user.is_staff = True
       user.is_superuser = True
       
       #user.save(using=self._bd)
       return user
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
   email               =models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60,unique = True)
   username            =models.CharField(verbose_name="username", max_length=30,unique = True)
   date_joined         =models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add = True)
   last_login          =models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now = True)
   is_admin            =models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_active           =models.BooleanField(default=True)
   is_staff            =models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_superuser        =models.BooleanField(default=False)
   hide_email          =models.BooleanField(default=False)
   
   objects = MyAccountManager()
   
   USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
   REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
   
   def __str__ (self):
       return self.username
   
   def has_perm(self,perm, obj=None):
       return self.is_admin
   
   def has_module_perm(self,app_label):
       return True
```

consecuentemente lo configuré en mi settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.Account'
```

e hice la respectiva migración,
creo mi super Usuario con:

```
manage.py createsuperuser
```

y me dirijo al login de admin de django para ver que no acepta ninguna credencial de ningun usuario creado

Usuarios que puedo visualizar en mi database por defecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para siempre recibir esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la información que muestra tu base de datos se ve que el flag `is_active` es correcto, pero las flags `is_superuser` y `is_staff` no son correctas.

Si te fijas en tu código de `create_superuser`, no haces `save` después de marcar las flags.